# jquery mobile, using forms and sql where clauses to return data from a local database

Tags: jquery, sql, forms

function advancedResults(price){

```
    db.transaction(function(txs) {
        txs.executeSql('SELECT * from skateboard where price="' + price1 + '" AND price="' + price2 + '"', [], function (txs, results) {
            var len = results.row.length, i;
            for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var AdvancedResult = results.row.item(i);
                var individualResult = '';
                individualResult += '<h3>' + AdvancedRecord.name + '</h3>';
                individualResult += '<img height="300" width="300" src="' + AdvancedRecord.image + '" />';
                individualResult += '<p>' + AdvancedRecord.desc + '</p>';
                individualResult += ' ';
                $('#advancedskateboards').html(individualResult);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is the function for getting the users input from the slider, and it sends back the name, image and description of the skateboards that fit the result, and posts them into the #advancedskateboards div on another page.

```
<div data-role="header" >
    <h1>Advanced Search</h1>
    <a href="#skateboardDatabase" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip">Back</a>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" class="demo">  
    <p>Use these advanced options to customise your search for a specific skateboard.</p>
    <form method="post" action="#advancedresults">
        <div data-role="rangeslider" data-popup-enabled="true" data-highlight="true">
            <label for="range-1a">Price (Pounds):</label>
            <input type="range" date-role="rangeslider" data-popup-enabled="true" name="price1" id="price1" min="0" max="100" value="40">
            <label for="range-1b">Price (Pounds):</label>
            <input type="range" date-role="rangeslider" data-popup-enabled="true" name="price2" id="price2" min="0" max="100" value="80">
        </div>
        <br>
        <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
            <label for="material">Select as many different materials as you'd like:</label>
            <select name="material" id="material" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Materials</option>
                <option value="map">Maple</option>
                <option value="pla">Plastic</option>
                <option value="car">Carbon Fibre</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>    
</div>

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="page" id="advancedresults">

<div data-role="header" >
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <a href="#advanced" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip">Back</a>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>Here is a list of your customised search results.</p>
    <div data-role="content" id="advancedskateboards" >
    <ul data-role="listview"  data-filter="true" data-inset="true" >  
        <!-- skateboards will be inserted here from the database using jquery -->
    </ul> 
</div>

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Sunderland Skateboard Company</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

The only problem is that when i click on the submit button, i want it to go to the 'advancedresults' page to then display the skateboards, but it is taking me back to the homepage and i don't know why.

Comment: Start by showing us what you've achieved so far.

Comment: your labels do not match the ids of their inputs id. write something like `<label for="myInput1">Klick me so my assigned input gets focused</label><input id="myInput" value=""/>`

Answer (score 0):

are you using php?

try something like

```
<?php
$sql = "select * from myTable where price between $_POST['price1'] AND $_POST['price2'] AND material IN (implode(',', $_POST['material '])) ..."
```

show us some examples by updating your post.

Comment: I am using brackets, and the live preview, along with the chrome developer tools to view my app, and i don't think php is supported by brackets

Comment: If it is possible to achieve this using jquery, javascript and sql that would be great, thanks

Comment: are you talking about localStorage? see [HTML5 Web SQL Database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Comment: Yes, do i use GET or POST? if i use GET that puts the users input from the slider and select box into the querystring, so how do i get their results displayed onto the page from there?

Comment: nothinig of that. use jQuery and catch and prevent the submit event or hide the submit button and work on the change events. then read the values of your form input fields and do something with your database. for the localStorage you do not need to send your values with get or post request anywhere.